# Novell Identity Manager (NIM) 3.6: How to make an image part of the resources for HTML reports?

Tags: html, image, reporting, novell-idm, netiq

This question might not belong here, and since this is related to HTML and reporting, I thought I could ask nonetheless.

I'm currently working to list all of the user identities in Designer for Identity Manager, by Novell.

I used the User Application connector and built the required queries. I also created a Provisioning and Request Definition with the necessary fields.

I can populate an HTML table with the results of the selected query, and get the user information from the Vault. Aside, I could use the organization's logo on the top-left-hand corner, the project name on the top-right with the report title just below on the right-hand side.

My concern is to set the organization's logo on the report.

> **Question**

1. How can I define this image logo as an image resource into NIM so that I can use it in my HTML identity report?
2. Shall it suffice to include the path of the image into the HTML document? If so, how shall I set this image path? I don't know much about HTML.

**EDIT #1**

I know that NIM uses Tomcat as Web Server to handle the responses. Perhaps moving the image in its directory should suffice?

If so, how can I find out what is this path where I can put the image, so that it is considered part of the Website resource?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Father Ramon, the patronizing saint of IDM, responded in this [thread in the Support Forums](http://forums.novell.com/novell-product-support-forums/identity-manager/im-engine-drivers/301280-hi.html).

It is the path to where to leave the file that is incredibly non-obvious.  He says the path is:

> /opt/novell/eDirectory/lib/dirxml/rules/manualtask/mt_files or
>   /usr/lib/dirxml/rules/manualtask/mt_files (depending on whether you are
>   using eDir 8.7.x or 8.8.x. IDM will automatically find it there and
>   attach when referenced.

But I see in another thread that some people had issues getting this to work.

You may find the [Support Forums](http://forums.novell.com/novell-product-support-forums/identity-manager/im-engine-drivers/) (I linked the IDM forum specifically) helpful.  A lot of people monitor those on this topic.

Also, you may find [Novell Cool Solutions](http://www.novell.com/communities/coolsolutions) helpful for user contributed content.  (I write as geoffc there).

In the IDM space, I have written a large number of articles that may help you in general, that are list on my [Wiki Page](http://wiki.novell.com/index.php/Geoffrey_Carman%27s_personal_collection).

If all that fails, the User Application Workflow engine uses a different email engine that may be more flexible.  (Thus you could call a Start Workflow for a workflow with just a single Email action in it).

Additionally in IDM 4 there is library, lib-AJC included, full of ECMA functions (Which would work perfectly well in IDM 3.6 and 3.5) that include a set of emailing functions.  If you have a driver configuration from IDM 3.6.1 odds are good you will have a lib-AJC in your tree already.

Comment: +1 It seems like you definitely know what you're talking about! Let me try this out tomorrow and let you know if I was able to solve the problem. To be honest, I am sure I'll be able to get to my goal with such answer! =) Thanks geoffc! =)

Comment: Hi geoffc! I have investigated throughout the directories, and a colleague says that the path provided in the above-quoted part of your answer is for the NIM resources itself or the like. I just don't understand everything here. So, to make sure I have gotten you right, I further in details explain my intention with a simple example so that we may both together talk the same speech. I have created a new query, let's say `users_by_department`. I then save, compare and update the eDirectory. Afterwards, I have created a Provisioning and Request Definition Form under the Attestations category[..]

Comment: [..] I have added fields to my form, and one of those is of type HTML. Then, from a StaticList, I choose the department from which I wish to get the list of users, and click an HTML Load button. Then, I launch my query: `IDVault.globalQuery(null, "users_department)`. I then pass this result to another Javascript function which process the users and build an HTML table that contains, for each row, the information of one user (cn, fullname and distinguishedName). This done, I wish to present this table with the company logo on the top-left corner, and the report title on the top-right corner.

Comment: And when I do: `htmlDoc += "<td style=\'background-image:url('companyLogo.png');border:0px;\'/>` That is more specifically what I'm trying to achieve. Any more clues as to where to copy the company logo so that I may reference it in my generated HTML string that I set as the value of the HTML field of my form? Thanks in advance for your assistance! =)

Comment: Will:  You are talking about Provisioning email versus DirXML Script policy email tokens.  These use different email engines underneath.  A good question.  Ask it on the Novell Support forums, at http://forums.novell.com in the Identity Manager, User Application forum.

Comment: @geoffc: In fact, I'm not talking about emails at all! =) I'm saying that I have created a form which calls queries according to the user's selection and then display an HTML table on screen with the found records in the meta-directory using the `IDVault.globalQuery()` method. I shall consider writing on either forums. Thanks for you assistance! =)